# from ..utils.fixes import rankdata ImportError: cannot import name 'rankdata' MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to run Skikit learn through Spyder on Anaconda

```
C:\Anaconda3>conda --version
conda 4.3.4
C:\Anaconda3>python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)
Spyder 2.3.8
```

I try to do the following:

```
print("Scikit-Learn", sklearn.__version__)
NameError: name 'sklearn' is not defined
from sklearn.model_selection import *
from ..utils.fixes import rankdata
ImportError: cannot import name 'rankdata'
Errors
```

Any idea why this error is coming as in Anaconda it shows the package as present but when I run through Spyder it gives the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using anaconda try:

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

Conda will try to handle de dependences and it may update other packages.

If this does not work, in the file fixes.py located in `<Anaconda_basedir>\lib\python3.5\site-packages\sklearn\utils` there is a line `if sp_version < (0,13, 0):` which conditions the import of `rankdata` if the version of scipy is lower than 0.13.0.

For som reason, if the version is > 0.13.0 it should use the `rankdata` from `scipy.stats`. But, at least in my case it wasn't, what I did was to add a `and False` so it gets the `rankdata` from `scipy`.

The final line is:

```
...
if sp_version < (0, 13, 0) and False:
    def rankdata(a, method='average'):
...
```

Comment: Thanks @GurstTavo I restarted my machine a couple of times and after that Scikit Learn started working.